# Change HTML according to SELECT

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to web development, and I seem to be stuck on achieving the following:

I have a standard SELECT/OPTIONS form type (a drop down list), and some textfields next to it. I want to change the format of the textfields, according to the selected option in the dropdown list.

The reason is this: I'm creating a simple web interface for a JDBC. Part of the requirement is that the user can add tuples into relations in the oracle SQL backend. The dropdown list lets them choose which relation to add tuples to. Then, the textfields should update to reflect the names and number of attributes in that relation.

I can get the names and # of attributes of a relation without a problem. My only problem is dynamically changing the HTML to make it appropriate for the selected relation. How can I use Javascript to get that kind of functionality?

EDIT: I don't have a working version. I can show you want I want, though.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <select>
                <option>Student</option>
                <option>Instructor</option>
            </select>
            Name: <input type="text" size=10></input>
            GPA: <input type="text" size=10></input>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you choose Student, then something like this would come up
[image]

However, if you wanted to add into the instructor table, then the attributes would be different, so something like this would be more appropriate
[image]

Again, I can retrieve the attribute names and the number of attributes without a problem. What I cannot do is dynamically change the HTML to reflect these changes.

Comment: Code examples, jsbin, anything? What have you tried so far?

Comment: For better understanding, Please provide a **working demo** (*code snippet,jsfiddle ...*)

Comment: None. I've looked up a couple of examples, but most of them talk about changing the SELECT and it's options. Nobody mentions changing HTML outside of the select.

Comment: Check the answer below. This is a naive question and a little google and little logical mapping will give u the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we're dynamically changing the contents of the `select` tag, it would be a good idea to use jQuery.

```js
$("select").on("change", function() {
        $(this).nextAll("input, label").remove();
        if ($(this).prop("value") === "Student") {
            $(this).after("</br></br><label for='name'>Name: </label>" +
                           "<input type='text' size='10'/>" +
                           "<label for='gpa'>GPA: </label>" +
                           "<input type='text' size='10'/>");
        }
       else {
            $(this).after("</br></br><label for='name'>Name: </label>" +
                           "<input type='text' size='10' />" +
                           "<label for='rank'>Rank: </label>" +
                           "<input type='text' size='10' />" +
                           "<label for='department'>Department: </label>" +
                           "<input type='text' size='10' />");
             }
    });
```

```css
input {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

label {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
    <option>Student</option>
    <option>Instructor</option>
</select>
```

You listen for changes in the selected option. You will then have to remove the previously applied labels and input elements existed. We use the `nextAll` function to search for siblings.

We can find which option was selected by using the `prop` method. We then have two conditionals for the two options.

To insert html, we use the `after` function.

Fiddle

Answer (score 0):

just make a simple show hide logic with js/Jquery, based on the value or text of ur selected value. if still are facing trouble put it in the comments i will give an example/demo

```
<select name="" id="user" onchange="newform()">
    <option value="student" selected>student</option>
    <option value="teacher">teacher</option>
</select>

<div id="student" >
    <label for="name">Name</label><input type="text" id="name"/>
    <label for="gpa">GPA</label><input type="text" id="gpa"/>
</div>
<div id="teacher" style="visibility:hidden">
    <label for="name">Name</label><input type="text" id="name"/>
    <label for="rank">rank</label><input type="text" id="rank"/>
    <label for="dept">dept</label><input type="text" id="dept"/>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function newform()
{
    var x = document.getElementById("user").value;
    if(x=="student")
    {
        document.getElementById("student").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("teacher").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("teacher").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("student").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, please include an example. I only need to see one working example. I can modify it to make it work for all of the different options in the select. I'm new to javascript, and unfamiliar with jQuery, so I'm curious to see how this is implemented.

Comment: @Naldhelaan i have made simple example. u need to do the css changes as per your requirement

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to attach an event listener for a `change` event on the `<select>` element. The function would look at the current value of the `<select>` element, and display/hide the parts of the form you wanted. I've provided a small working demo using plain/vanilla JavaScript below.

```js
function toggle(ev) {
  // get the input elements, and convert the results into an array
  var inputs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('input'));
  
  // clear values from all inputs
  // (that way the user doesn't accidentally enter a value, switch options, and upload unwanted data)
  inputs.forEach(input => input.value = '');

  // hide/display fields depending on which option is selected
  // #name is always displayed
  switch (ev.target.value) {
    case 'Student':
      document.querySelector('#rank').style.display = 'none';
      document.querySelector('#dept').style.display = 'none';
      document.querySelector('#gpa').style.display = 'block'; // or flex, or inline, etc. depending on your CSS
      break;
    case 'Instructor':
      document.querySelector('#rank').style.display = 'block';
      document.querySelector('#dept').style.display = 'block';
      document.querySelector('#gpa').style.display = 'none';
      break;
  }
}

document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change', toggle);
```

```html
<form>

<select>
  <option selected>Student</option>
  <option>Instructor</option>
</select>

<label id=name>
  <p>Name</p>
  <input type=text>
</label>

<label id=rank style='display: none;'>
  <p>Rank</p>
  <input type=text>
</label>

<label id=dept style='display: none;'>
  <p>Department</p>
  <input type=text>
</label>

<label id=gpa>
  <p>GPA</p>
  <input type=number max=5.0 min=0.0>
</label>

<button type=submit>Submit</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

how to post form data after click submit button on form

```js
 
      $(".MyToggle").click(function() {
    $(this).val()=='yes'?$(this).closest('div').find('.Questions').show():$(this).closest('div').find('.Questions').hide();
});

$("select").on("change", function() {
        $(this).nextAll("input, label").remove();
        if ($(this).prop("value") === "newzealand") {
            $(this).after("</br></br><label for='name'>Name: </label>" +
                           "<input type='text' class='form-control' size='10'/>" +
                           "<label for='gpa'>GPA: </label>" +
                           "<input type='text' class='form-control' size='10'/>");
        }
       else if ($(this).prop("value") === "australia") {
           $(this).after("</br></br><label for='name'>Name: </label>" +
                           "<input type='text' class='form-control' size='10'/>" +
                           "<label for='gpa'>GPA: </label>" +
                           "<input type='text' class='form-control' size='10'/>");
          
          
             }
             
             
              else if ($(this).prop("value") === "Newzealand-Resident") {
            $(this).after("</br></br><label for='name'>Name: </label>" +
                           "<input type='text' class='form-control' size='10'/>" +
                           "<label for='gpa'>GPA: </label>" +
                           "<input type='text' class='form-control' size='10'/>");
          
          
          
             }
             
             
             else if ($(this).prop("value") === "Newzealand-Resident") {
            $(this).after("</br></br><label for='name'>Name: </label>" +
                           "<input type='text' class='form-control' size='10'/>" +
                           "<label for='gpa'>GPA: </label>" +
                           "<input type='text' class='form-control' size='10'/>");
          
          
          
             }  
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='control-group'>
    <label class='control-label' for='work_visa'>Type of Work Visa<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div class='controls'>
         <select name="work_visa" required="required" id="work_visa"  class="input-medium">
            <option value='' selected="selected">Choose</option>
<option value='newzealand'>New Zealand Citizen</option>
<option value='australia'>Australian Citizen</option>
<option value='Newzealand-Resident'>NZ Resident</option>
<option value='Work Visa'>Work Visa</option>
<option value='Work Permit'>Work Permit</option>
<option value='Work and Holiday Visa'>Work and Holiday Visa</option>
<option value='Student Work Visa'>Student Work Visa</option>

        </select>
        
    </div>
</div>
```